# In programming terminology, what do you call the difference between these instructions:

Tags: php, python, terminology

PHP: strpos($haystack, $needle);

and

Python: haystack.find(needle)

It seems like python uses the latter method more often, and PHP the former. But is there a name for these two ways of doing it? I'm looking for the name of the style of programming.

Is it correct to call the one procedural and the other object-oriented programming? Or is that simplifying matters?

Comment: [Difference between a method and a function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/155609/difference-between-a-method-and-a-function)

Comment: `Procedural style` and `Object oriented style`

Comment: thanks @bansi, that is what I was going for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first is a global function that takes two operands of some type and operates on them. its common in the older-style procedural programming paradigm.

the seconds is a member-function of the String class (of which "haystack" is an instance of) which takes one operand. its part of the object-oriented programming paradigm.